# Finitely generated, periodic group such that each conjugacy class is finite must be finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

This is essentially a repeat of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873387/finitely-generated-group-3). However, the OP didn't seem to put in any work towards a solution and didn't provide context. Nevertheless, I'm still interested in the solution, and I am having difficulty.

To repeat:

> Let $G$ be a finitely generated, periodic group such that each conjugacy class is finite. Does it follow that $G$ is finite?

Here's what I have done which was spurred by Derek Holt's hint in the previous question:

Let $G$ be generated by $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.

Since each conjugacy class is finite this means that $C_G(x)$ has finite index in $G$ for all $x\in G$. We also have in general that if two subgroups have finite index, then their intersection has finite index. Thus $C_G(x_1)\cap\cdots\cap C_G(x_n)$ has finite index in $G$.

This intersection is none other than $Z(G)$ since every element of $G$ can be written as a finite product of the $x_i$. So we know that $Z(G)$ has finite index.

I have yet to use the fact that each element of $G$ has finite order, but don't immediately see how that is going to help.

I am mostly interested in a hint to get me to the solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the quoted question, it was not assumed that every element of $G$ is a torsion element, only that the elements $x_i$ are torsion elements. I think you need to use Schur's Theorem that $G/Z(G)$ finite implies that the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ is finite.

Comment: Ah thanks. I missed that part. I wasn't aware of Schur's Theorem. I'll work on it some more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to provide a quick answer to your weaker question (the one you actually post, as opposed to the one in the comments). I don't want to answer the "full" version, as I think some time should pass before re-asking and answering a closed question (say, 5 days).

So, you proved that $Z(G)=C_G(x_1)\cap\ldots C_G(x_n)$ has finite index in $G$. We'll start from there.

1. Finite-index subgroups of finitely generated groups are also finitely generated, so $Z(G)$ is finitely generated.
2. $Z(G)$ is abelian.

The above two facts, along with the assumption that $G$ is torsion, implies that $Z(G)$ is finite. As $Z(G)$ has finite index in $G$, $G$ must also be finite. This proves your result.

Comment: I think there is another proof (to the more general question). Let $Y$ be the union of all conjugacy classes of elements of $X$. $Y$ is finite so we can assume that $G$ is generated by a finite normal subset. If we proceed by induction on the number of conjugacy classes in $Y$, the question can be reduced to the case where Y contains only one conjugacy class $\{x^{g_1},x^{g_2},…,x^{g_n}\}$. Any element of G can be written as a product of the $x^{g_i}$ in such away that xgi appears in the expression before any $x^{g_j}$, i less than j.

Comment: This leaves just a finite number of possibilities!!. Note that the result is old, it is refered as Dicman's Lemma (14.5.7) in Robinson's "A course in the theory of groups". The proof given in the book is not very different from the above.